# Developing a check_win function for tic tac toe game, if statements are not working properly

Tags: python-3.x

Please let me know where I am making a mistake:

```
def display_board(board):


    print(board[7] + '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9] )

    print(board[4] + '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])

    print(board[1] + '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
    return

test_board1 = ['#','0','X','0','X','0','X','0','X','0']

def win_check(board,marker):

        if board[1] == marker and board[2] == marker and board[3] == marker :
            print('won')
        elif board[4] == marker and board[5] == marker and board[6] == marker:
            print('won')
        elif board[7] == marker and board[8] == marker and board[9] == marker:
            print('won')
        elif board[1] == marker and board[4] == marker and board[7] == marker:
            print('won')
        elif board[2] == marker and board[4] == marker and board[8] == marker:
            print('won')
        elif board[3] == marker and board[6] == marker and board[9] == marker:
            print('won')
        elif board[1] == marker and board[5] == marker and board[9] == marker:
            print('won')
        elif board[3] == marker and board[5] == marker and board[7] == marker:
            print('won')

display_board(test_board1)
win_check(test_board1, 'X')
```

Comment: Please explain what you are expecting this code to do, and what it is doing which is different from your expectation.

Comment: I am expecting to print 'won' if you get to have same marker in any of the specific row or column including both diagonals of display_board.
In the above scenario, statement 'win_check(test_board1, 'X')' is not meeting any if statement but still its giving an output of 'won'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there. This line is the one causing you problems:

```
        elif board[2] == marker and board[4] == marker and board[8] == marker:
```

It should be:

```
        elif board[2] == marker and board[5] == marker and board[8] == marker:
```